# What exactly does Omen's Paranoia ability do?

Tags: valorant

Omen's Paranoia ability is described as:

> EQUIP a blinding orb. FIRE to throw it forward, briefly Nearsighting
> and Deafening all players it touches. This projectile can pass
> straight through walls.

I'd like to know:

1. How nearsighting is Nearsight (i.e. how many meters is your vision range reduced to)?
2. How brief is briefly (i.e. how long are you Nearsighted/Deafened for)?
3. What exactly does Deafened do? A description I found said:

> An agent with a Deafen debuff will have their audio severely dampened
> and their minimap will become obscured. This will also prevent HUD VFX
> for some enemy abilities from appearing on an affected player's
> screen. The global casting quotes for enemy ultimate abilities can
> still be heard by deafened agents.

3.A. Does having audio dampened mean that sounds they hear are just quieter, or does it mean that    they can't hear things that are farther away that they'd normally be able to?

3.B. Also, what does an obscured minimap mean? Can a Deafened player just not see their minimap anymore?

3.C Also, I'm assuming that since it says that players can still hear enemy's ultimates right after it says that only some abilities don't show up on the minimap that ultimates *do* show up on the minimap? Or is this completely wrong?